# <undefined> html tag getting generated in angular2 beta 0 app

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template, angular2-routing

I am currently using the latest angular.beta.0 and have followed their quick start tutorial with the router tutorial.
The app works fine but upon inspecting the generated DOM, there is an `<undefined>` tag generated. It isnt causing any issues but I would want it to be clarified.

The undefined tag contains the whole app markup in it.

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When Routing you can skip the selector in the components, which is valid. But they will appear as *undefined*. That may look ugly, so you can avoid it by specifying a selector which will work as a name and won't match any custom element in your templates.

So this will produce an `undefined` custom element in your DOM

```js
// Some component loaded through routing    
@Component({
    // No selector!
    template : 'Some template'
})
```

This will not

```js
// Some component loaded through routing    
@Component({
    selector : 'some-component',
    template : 'Some template'
})
```

This case will show `some-component` in the DOM instead of `undefined`.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, I did not provide a selector for my component and yes, your solutions works! Thank You